# What happens if there are 2 answers with same highest number of votes when the bounty is expired?

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

This is a really weird case but I wonder what happens if the bounty expires and there are multiple answers with same highest number of votes? (e.g., 2 answers with 8 up votes). How does the system decide which answer to give the half of the bounty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The oldest answer is awarded the bounty.

From the [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) FAQ:

> Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, an eligible answer can be automatically awarded *half* the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible for automatic awarding are as follows:
>
> - The answer must be given *after* the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.