# Can a bounty be split in the case of an expired bounty?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties, expired-bounty

Firstly, I understand why [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users) was declined, and I even personally agree with the decision: there should be one best answer, and the system should be designed to encourage that.

However, in the case of a tie and an expired bounty, then as [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) and [What happens if there are 2 answers with same highest number of votes when the bounty is expired?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100042/) explain, automatic awarding awards (half) the bounty to the *oldest* answer.

I feel that:

1. This encourages hasty answers on bounty questions (which are then improved by edits later).
2. This encourages unnatural (contrary to what they would have done otherwise) unvote/downvote sniping to break the tie at the last second.

For those reasons, it seems to me like it would make more sense if the half-bounty were split among the highest voted answers in the case of a tie (not awarding it at all in the case of a tie would still significantly encourage sniping).